# C# to C++/CX: How to choose a type turn into a IVector

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

I am writing a C# project and it will use native library, we use `winRT` as middle layer, I need to call a function defined as
 `void 
addPoints(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<double>^ >^ Point_)`, I wonder how to choose a type in C# to map to IVector, I notive Vector, but it only contains x and y, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can pass anything to that method that implements IList.

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe IList will help.